How to delete file and folder with irregular names
the content of some folder is like that:

Folder name is empty
File name is asterisk
I can find inode of these file and folder
OS - z/OS OMVS, so, there is no option -delete on find command
How can I safely delete these?
If there is no safe way, I can leave it as it is.

If there's no -delete there should still be the possibility to use -exec rm {} \;, right?

first - list inodes
ls -ali

for the directory (use your inode value):
find .  -type d -inum 2656 -exec ls -la {} \;
find .  -type d -inum 2656 -exec rm -r {} \;

for the file (use your inode value):
find .  -type f -inum 413 -exec cat {} \;
find .  -type f -inum 413 -exec rm  {} \;

Thanks @Kusalananda for the hint.

Note that for a file of type directory, ls lists the contents of the directory, not the directory itself (for which you need the -d option). rm won't remove a directory unless you pass the -r option, but then note that it will also remove all the contents recursively. Then you should add a -prune predicate to tell find not to try and descend into that directory as it should be gone by the time rm terminates.

Thank you @StéphaneChazelas, I wanted to check content of directory before delete, so not used -d.
As for the -r option I missed it first time and it warned me, but when I retired with -r it said there is no such directory, so I guess it was removed without -r during first run

No, if you ran rm without -r, no directories would have been deleted.

Yeah, you are right. Not sure how I messed up. But now I retried with a test directory, indeed -r is mandatory. I will update my command.
